# Unable to login to my Google Play console

Tags: google-play-console

I had a Google workspace account earlier having more than 20 emails with an agency. Due to billing issues, I migrated my earlier emails to newly created Google workspace account of my own company. It was successful. But Google Play Console account associated with earlier email account is now not available and whenever I try to logging with new email account (same email) it asks for new developer account. I want to update my apps available in previous account. Any help.

I tried all my knowledge to find a solution and also asked google community for this but no answer at all. This is the link
`https://support.google.com/googleplay/thread/249831983/unable-to-login-to-play-console-account`